# JAVA: How to find a specific object in array matching certain criteria?

Tags: java, arrays, contains, indexof

I'm trying to find a certain block from my Block object Array by using the X, and Y specified from the UI.  I have been using a locator array making duplicate entries alongside the main array in order to try this.

```
public Block get(int x, int y) {
            int index = 0;
            index = blocks.indexOf(locator[x][y], true);
            return blocks.get(index);
        }
```

This however spits back an  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1/

It seems like it would work but am I overlooking something?

This is the Error Returned

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array.get(Array.java:126)
    at com.myname.javatest.World.get(World.java:80)
    at com.myname.javatest.ui.UserInterface.renderPositions(UserInterface.java:35)
    at com.myname.javatest.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:58)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:187)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
```

Comment: Please post the *complete* error message.

Comment: indexOf returns -1 when the item is not found. Do you need a check before calling .get()?

Comment: You should edit your original question to include the error message rather than posting it as a comment.

Comment: I added a notnull check and it seems to work. However, after a while my locator array runs out of space as the game is randomly generated....I may need a new approach.